# Python: set class method as class attribut

Tags: python, function, static, attributes, callback

The following seems not to be valid in python 3:

```
class A:
 callback = A.callback_function

 def callback_function(self):
  pass
```

You'll get an error saying type 'A' is not defined. Is it because 'A' cannot be refered to in it self? Is there anyway I can achieve this type of functionality?

What I'm trying to do is something like this: I have a base class:

```
class Base:
 callback = Base.ignore

 def ignore(self):
  pass

 def some_other_function(self):
  self.callback()
```

In a subclass I'd like to set another callback function:

```
class Derived(Base):
 callback = Derived.special_function

 def special_function(self):
  do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you can just name your function `callback`, and it'll be just the same, but if you really insist on this way:

```
class A:
    def callback_function(self): pass

    callback = callback_function
```